# Google App Engine, define a Preprocessing class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, django-templates, preprocessor

I am trying to define a `base request handling` class so that the webapp pages may inherit some basic methods and variable which otherwise would be required to be repeatedly be defined for each page of the application. A sort of similar functionality like `django preprocessors`.  This is my base class from which other pages inherit:

```
class BasePage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):    
        self.user = users.get_current_user()    
        self.template_values = {
                'user': self.user,       
                'environ': self,   #I don't like the idea of passing the whole environ object to a template

                ##The below three functions cannot be executed during _init_ because of absence of self.request 
                #'openid_providers': self.openid_providers(),  
                #'logout_url': self.get_logout_url(),
                #'request': self.get_request(),
            }           

    ##A sort of similar functionality like render_to_response in django
    def render_template(self, template_name, values = None, *args, **kwargs):
        #PATH is the directory containing the templates
        if values: 
            for value in values:  self.template_values[value] = values[value]
        self.response.out.write(template.render(PATH+template_name, self.template_values, *args, **kwargs))                 

    ##Returns request as the name suggests
    def logout_url(self):
        return users.create_logout_url(self.request.url)

    ##Returns request as the name suggests
    def request(self):
        return request

    ##Returns openid login urls        
    def openid_providers(self):
        #OPENID_POVIDERS  is a list of dictionary 
        for p in OPENID_PROVIDERS:
             p['login_url'] = users.create_login_url(self.request.get('next', '/') , p['name'], p['url'])
        return OPENID_PROVIDERS
```

Everything is working fine except that I cannot pass some variables during initialization as self.request is not available. So for a workaround what I did is pass on whole self variable as a template variable.

Is there some other way to provide the template variables (request, logout_url etc) to the templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved that problem in my AppEngine code by using the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Basically, the base class looks like:

```
class MyBasePage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        # common setup/init stuff here, 
        # omitted for this discussion

    def Setup(self):
        # request handling setup code needed in both GET/POST methods, like
        # checking for user login, getting session cookies, etc.
        # omitted for this discussion

    def get(self, *args):
        self.Setup()
        # call the derived class' 'DoGet' method that actually has 
        # the logic inside it
        self.DoGet(*args)

    def post(self, *args):
        self.Setup()
        # call the derived class' 'DoPost' method 
        self.DoPost(*args)

    def DoGet(self, *args):
        ''' derived classes override this method and 
            put all of their GET logic inside. Base class does nothing.'''
        pass

    def DoPost(self, *args):
        ''' derived classes override this method and 
            put all of their POST logic inside. Base class does nothing.'''
        pass
```

...your derived classes then mostly just need to worry about the guts of those `DoGet()` and `DoPost()` methods.

Comment: thanks! I was thinking in lines of defining custom get, posts in the base class and using super(), but this DoPost, DoGet seems great!! I think this is good for my small project which don't need many django features.

Answer (score 5):

A much simpler solution than bgporter's is to do the common setup in the `initialize` method of `webapp.RequestHandler`.  Here's an example from work, where we wanted to add a Django-like `is_ajax` method to the request object:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, request, response):
        super(BaseHandler, self).initialize(request, response)
        # Add a Django-like is_ajax() method to the request object
        request.is_ajax = lambda: \
            request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

This method is called to, uh, initialize each request handler with the current request and response objects, before the appropriate `get` or `post` (or whatever) methods are called.

Comment: Yeah, it's not very obvious how you can do things like this. I'm not exactly sure why the handlers don't just use `__init__` to do the same thing.